# Poor English questions leads to poor English answers and general confusion

Tags: discussion, non-english-speakers

[Can an abstract class have only method signatures without implementation like interfaces?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11323612/can-an-abstract-class-have-only-method-signature-as-interfaces-without-implement/11323794#comment14906673_11323794) is worded very poorly, and can mean a number of different things. Apparently, non-English or English-second-language speakers, or perhaps just poor English speakers, are unable to understand the question and are providing equally misleading answers.

I'm unable to edit any of it because I don't know the intent. Is this a vote to close? There's a reasonable question in there, but no one really knows what each other is talking about.

Comment: Vote to close as "Not a real question" if you don't understand it, but make sure to ask for clarification in a comment.

Comment: I don't think the OP has English skills to provide clarification. See link.

Comment: I never assumed the OP had the skills—leaving a comment is just letting people know why you vote to close. And you're giving the OP a heads up. That's all.

Comment: I understood the question, at least up until item number 3, which is ambigous

Answer (score 16):

If the question is beyond comprehension, it must be closed as NARQ.

Don't worry much about closing--if it gets fixed, it can be reopened. Though I usually comment and ask for a fix first, and then VTC if no fix is provided (it prevents newbies from getting annoyed at "preemptive" closes)

As for the "Poor English question-->poor English answer", the reason for that is simple: The post was in a form of discombobulated English unique to Indians--thus only those who use this form of English posted, along with a few others who somehow understood the question.

I myself would be able to clarify the question--except that I don't understand the topic well enough to make sense of it:\ (I don't see how a "methid signature" can be an interface, but I'm probably ignorant about this)

Comment: +1 Even if the question has some grammatical and/or spelling mistakes it should not be closed arbitrarily. If you realize that their is some problem in the question, why not edit it, that is what community is all about ? If one can't make edits than they can ask in comments..

Comment: @anD the point is, you can't fix it if you yourself can't understand it. And closing isn't necessarily a punishment, it's just a time-out box "hold your horses until this question is brought up to scratch"

Comment: "The post was in a form of discombobulated English unique to Indians" - this made my day. thank you